# Drag and Drop in Expandable List View(Android)

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, expandablelistview

I have an `Expandable List View` showing the items from the database(Sqlite) which is working perfectly. What I want is to add the **drag and drop** functionality on my expandable list(on **Parent Group**) and reflect it back on my database. I know it is possible with simple List View, but is it also possible with the expandable List View.? If it is then please tell me how or any working example which is available on internet.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should do it on your own if you know how to do it in a listview , only the listeners or methods would change there must be minor changes

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: check this https://github.com/sreekumarsh/android/tree/master/Drag%20N%20Drop

Comment: @Jagdeep have you found any solution for your question ? If you have any solution then let me know

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your specifications.
But hopefully this [sample](https://github.com/imbryk/drag-sort-listview) may give you an idea.

-Sathya